# Should i disown my mother?

Tags: allah

My mother has relationships outside of her marriage. My father is alive. We are ashamed of her deeds. We gave her many chances but she didn’t change. She promised to change but didn’t. She even commits zinah. We face many obstacles because of her and our life became stressful. Can i disown her?

Comment: Relevant: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56991/

Answer (score 1):

This is a very serious matter and you need to be absolutely sure that adultery had taken place. Kissing and other illicit things do not count. If you father is absolutely sure then he can go for the **li’aan** process

*Li’aan is done as described in the verse in which Allaah says* *(interpretation of the meaning): *

*“And for those who accuse their wives, but have no* *witnesses except themselves, let the testimony of one of* *them be four testimonies (i.e. testifies four times) by Allah* *that he is one of those who speak the truth.*

*And the fifth (testimony should be) the invoking of the Curse* *of Allaah on him if he be of those who tell a lie (against her).*

*But it shall avert the punishment (of stoning to death) from* *her, if she bears witness four times by Allaah, that he (her* *husband) is telling a lie.*

*And the fifth (testimony) should be that the Wrath of Allah* *be upon her if he (her husband) speaks the truth”*

*[al-Noor 24:6-9]*

Should she deny, they will part ways and that I think is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,

I don't think you should disown her. Yes, her actions are faulty, but in the end, she is your mother. Let Allah (swt) deal with her sins, but you should still do your part as a child.

> Abu Huraira reported: A man asked the Messenger of Allah, peace and
> blessings be upon him, “Who is most deserving of my good company?” The
> Prophet said, “Your mother.” The man asked, “Then who?” The Prophet
> said “Your mother.” The man asked again, “Then who?” The Prophet said,
> “Your mother.” The man asked again, “Then who?” The Prophet said,
> “Your father.”