# Is it haram for a daughter to use nasty words against parents?

Tags: fiqh, parents

If the father is a tyrant, then can the daughter use curse/nasty words (son of a b***h) against her father? I'm asking this because Allah says in [4:148](https://quran.com/4/148?translations=17,27,84,85),

> "Allah does not like the evil words to be said openly except from
> anyone wronged. Allah is All-Hearing, All-Knowing."

So, if a daughter has been wronged severely, can she use bad/nasty words against her father?

Comment: Muhammad ﷺ had been wronged for majority of his life, yet he never cursed anyone.

Comment: You may never do so. You know Abraham/Ibrahim (AS) his father threatened him that he will stone him If Ibrahim doesn't leave his house because Ibrahim did not believe in his father's god and believed in Allah. You know what Ibrahim said: "Salamun Alayk" Peace be upon you my father and he said that he will pray to Allah about your iman.

No matter how harsh your parents are unless they are doing anything against deen you may never say anything against them not even an "UFF" and even if they are against deen Islam you should just not follow them while still respecting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A child is forbidden from abusing its parents.

> وقضى ربك ... وبالوالدين إحسانا ... فلا تقل لهما أف ولا تنهرهما وقل لهما قولا كريما
>
> And your Lord has decreed ... to parents, good treatment ... say not to them [so much as], "uff," and do not repel them but speak to them a noble word.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 17:23](https://quran.com/17/23?translations=20)</sup>

> إن من أكبر الكبائر أن يلعن الرجل والديه
>
> It is one of the greatest sins that a man should curse his parents.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5973)</sup>

This is an absolute prohibition and there is no evidence which exempts it. It is not even permitted to take Qisas from parents, so anything else is even less substantial.

Comment: Could you please show a reference for this claim, "It is not even permitted to take Qisas from parents"

Comment: Please search the site.

Comment: could you please share the link here? I haven't found any post related to Qisas against parents.

Comment: See e.g. the end of the answer [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/56999/20218)